# PHP: not maintaining a desired value in $_POST method

Tags: php, variables, post, default-value

I have a variable $numA & $numB which contain a value of 10 & 40.

```
$numA = 10; $numB = 40;
```

Everytime I click each button "+" & "-" the value of the other variable returns to the default value. I want that every time I press the buttons the value each variable value changes not to the default value but the new value assigned to it.

Ex:(when I press "-" and "+")

```
desired output: 
$numA = 20;
$numB = 20;
```

It's could be done without using $_SESSION method? here's my code below:

```
<?php
    $numA = 10;

    if (isset($_POST["add"]))
    {
        $numA = $_POST["add"];
        $addition = $numA + 10;
        $numA = $addition;

    }

    $numB = 40;

    if (isset($_POST["substract"]))
    {
        $numB = $_POST["substract"];
        $substraction = $numB - 20;
        $numB = $substraction;
    }

?>

<form name="add" method="post">
    <input type="hidden"  name="add" value="<?php echo $numA ?>" />
    <input type="submit"  value="+" />
    <?php echo "ADDITION= ", $numA, '<BR>'; ?>
</form>

<form name="subtract" method="post">
    <input type="hidden"  name="substract" value="<?php echo $numB ?>" />
    <input type="submit"  value="-" />
    <?php echo "SUBSTRACTION= ", $numB, '<BR>'; ?>  
</form>
```

Kindly help me with this one. Please provide an explanation. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

A session or cookie would be the only way to do this (unless you wanted these values to be the same for everyone, then you could put them in a flat file or database). You could do it via a `$_GET` as well, but it would afford you less control.

The reason is that there is no inherent persistence between script calls. This is the nature of web based programming. Each call is autistic from the next unless you pass something along between calls. So in your script, you will always start with `$numA` as 10 because there's nothing persisted. Set your numbers inside a session instead and they will persist for that user

```
session_start(); // Have to call this before using session variables
if(!isset($_SESSION['numA'])) $_SESSION['numA'] = 10;
```

Now you can use `$_SESSION['numA']` and your values will be incremented and decremented as you run your script.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the stored values each time because you are explicitly setting the values of `$numA` and `$numB` each time you run the script.  Also, you are dealing with two forms so only one set of values gets POST'ed, so you can just check for a particular variable.  This code will get you what you want (click "+" or "-" to change both values to 20) and the numbers keep changing each subsequent click.

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST["add"]))
    {
        $numA = $_POST["add"];
        $numA += 10;
    } else {
        $numA = 10;
    }


    if (isset($_POST["substract"]))
    {
        $numB = $_POST["substract"];
        $numB -= 20;
    } else {
        $numB = 40;
    }

?>

<form id="math" method="post">
    <input type="hidden"  name="add" value="<?php echo $numA ?>" />
    <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('math').submit();" value="+" />
    <?php echo "ADDITION= ", $numA, '<BR>'; ?>

    <input type="hidden"  name="substract" value="<?php echo $numB ?>" />
    <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('math').submit();" value="-" />
    <?php echo "SUBSTRACTION= ", $numB, '<BR>'; ?>  
</form>
```

Beyond that you will need to pick a storage method of some kind if you want data persistence.  It can be sessions, cookies, text file, $_GET variables, etc., but in the end you have to get data passed between calls.

Comment: everytime I click the button it will execute the 2 script. I only want to execute 1 script at the same time but it gonna maitain the desired value of each variable not the default value also I don't want to use some javascript.

Comment: Well then you will need to use some kind of storage method then.  Sessions are easiest in my opinion.  Is there some reason you can't use them to store you values?  You problem of persistence is solved by using them.

Comment: mhm I just want to figure out if it's possible do it without storing values in session, database, textfile etc. i think switch statement will work? or not?

Comment: Logic wise you can do it several ways, but due to the stateless nature between server and client you need to use some mechanism to transfer data between the two. Hence if you want data from one request to go into the next, you must use some kind of storage.